# Unexpected difference between executing code in the shell or in a sub-shell

Tags: bash, subshell

Is this difference between executing code in the shell or in a sub-shell expected?

```
$ a() { echo ${@: -1} ; }
$ echo "echo ${*: -1}" > b
$ chmod +x b
$ a 1 2 3
3
$ ./b 1 2 3
bash
$
```

---

Debian Sid
Bash version 5.2.15

Comment: Could you show us what is in `b`? (yes, this seems to be pretty sane)

Comment: @MarcusMüller `b` is created in the `echo` statement.  Or are  you asking something else?

Comment: @RonJohn exactly. Look at the contents of `b` after you've created it.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I see your point.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here:

```
$ echo "echo ${*: -1}" > b
```

that `"${*: -1}"` is double-quoted, and so it expands immediately. When the slice notation is used with `$*` or `$@`, it looks at the list of `$0`, `$1`, ..., not just the list of the positional parameters starting at `$1`. Negative indexes count back from the end, so starting at `-1` gives the last element of that list.

Since you likely have no positional parameters in an interactive shell, taking the last element of that list gives `$0`, the shell name. In your case, that appears to be `bash`, and the file `b` will contain `echo bash`.

In the function, `${@: -1}` sees the positional parameters of the function itself, the last one of which is `3`.

If you want to store the string `echo ${*: -1}` in a file, use single quotes instead to prevent the expansion. It would be better to also add double-quotes so the expansion is quoted when it happens, so e.g.

```
echo 'echo "${*: -1}"' > c
```

There's no subshell here, though, just a function and an external script.

Comment: I think the OP is referring to the shell that executes the script when they say subshell.